# NextJS: Force dependency with outputStandalone option

Tags: reactjs, next.js

With the new `outputStandalone` experimental feature (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#automatically-copying-traced-files-experimental) we can, after the build, have a *standalone* folder that contains the necessary dependencies, we simply copy it into our docker and don't need to rebuild inside the docker. It automatically detects the necessary dependencies in the source code UNLESS that dependency is only used in our package.json.

We use `cross-env` to start our Next app and of course this library is never imported in our source code, yet it needs to be present in the node_modules of the standalone folder.

So how can I force `@vercel/nft` to include a specific dependency ?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, we ended up removing this dependency from our start script. But we had several ideas : make docker install this dependency in the standalone folder, import this dependency (server side, no need to to have it client side if we can avoid it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My case was that our [dockerized Next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) project used [Knex.js](https://knexjs.org/), where [migrations](https://knexjs.org/guide/migrations.html) were invoked with a npm script. Following this, some dependencies only required for `knex.migrations()` were never included in the standalone output.

---

**Credits to [sbstn](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/node-next-js-with-newrelic-next-and-outputstandalone/184834/13),** you can use [unstable_includeFiles](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#caveats) to create a list of dependencies, which should be included in the standalone output. This solution scans for `.js` and `.json` in a `node_modules/` directory.

It should be highlighted that this setting is not available inside `next.config.js`, but as a page config prop, meaning it has to be exported inside a [`export const config = {}`](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#the-config-key-is-now-an-export-on-a-page) from a page different from `_app.jsx` and `/api` routes.

```js
// pages/index.jsx

export default function Home(){
   ...
}

const requiredStandaloneDependencies = [
    // some required deps that have not been included in standalone
    "commander",
    "debug",
    "escalade",
    "get-package-type",
    "getopts",
    "interpret",
    "lodash",
    "pg-connection-string",
    "rechoir",
    "resolve-from",
    "tarn",
    "tildify",
];

export const config = {
    unstable_includeFiles: requiredStandaloneDependencies.map(
        (dep) => `node_modules/${dep}/**/*.+(js|json)`
    ),
};
```

---

As a final thought for my case, where migrations are invoked with a custom npm script, `npm run migrate:latest`, I should also be able to circumvent the issue [using programmatically invoked migrations](https://knexjs.org/guide/migrations.html#latest). I'm just unsure as to how I add the method to the Next.js project tree to be run during runtime initialization.